# Check if *output* node already exists

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to merge two files A.xml and map.xml with "Node" elements according to the following rule (nodes are distinguished by @Name):

1. If the element in map.xml has a Src attribute, the element from map should be copied to output
2. If the element exists in A and map and does NOT have @Src, it should be copied from A
3. If the element exists in A but not in map, it should be ignored (with warning)
4. If the element exists in map but not in A, the (empty) element shall be generated

Example:

map.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<Node Name="ParentNode">
    <Node Name="Child1" Src="Child1/"/>
    <Node Name="Child2" Src="Child2/"/>
    <Node Name="Child3" Src="Child3/"/>

    <Node Name="Child4">
        <Node Name="Child4_Sub1" />
        <Node Name="Child4_Sub2" Src="Child4_Sub2/"/>
    </Node>

    <Node Name="Child5" />
</Node>
```

A.xml:

```
<Node Name="ParentNode">
    <Node Name="Child4">
        <Node Name="Child4">
            <Node Name="Child4_Sub1">
                <!-- Here are many other elements -->
            </Node>
        </Node>
    </Node> 
    <!-- Here are many other elements -->
    <Node Name="Child1">
        <!-- Here are many other elements -->
    </Node>
    <!-- Here are many other elements -->

    <Node Name="ChildFoo">
        <!-- Here are many other elements -->
    </Node>
</Node>
```

The result should be:

```
<Node Name="ParentNode">
    <Node Name="Child4">
        <Node Name="Child4">
            <Node Name="Child4_Sub1">
                <!-- Here are many other elements -->
            </Node>
            <Node Name="Child4_Sub2" />
        </Node>
    </Node> 
    <!-- Here are many other elements -->
    <Node Name="Child1" Src="Child1" />
    <!-- Here are many other elements -->

    <Node Name="Child2" Src="Child2" />
    <Node Name="Child3" Src="Child3" />
</Node>
```

My XSLT script is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0">
    <xsl:param name="mapFile" required="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="MapDiagram" select="document($mapFile,/*)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="CurrentDocument" select="/" />

    <!-- handle Node elements in A.xml -->
    <xsl:template match="Node">
        <xsl:variable name="MyName" select="@Name"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$MapDiagram//Node[@Name = $MyName]">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$MapDiagram//Node[@Name = $MyName]/@Src">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="$MapDiagram//Node[@Name = $MyName]"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <Node Name="{@Name}" Type="{@Type}">
                            <xsl:apply-templates/>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="$MapDiagram//Node[@Name = $MyName]" mode="MapDiagram" />
                        </Node>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:message terminate="no">WARNING: Node "<xsl:value-of select="@Name"/>" not found in map file, ignoring</xsl:message>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- handle Node elements from map file -->
    <xsl:template match="Node" mode="MapDiagram">
        <xsl:variable name="MyName" select="@Name"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="not($CurrentDocument//Node[@Name = $MyName])">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:apply-templates mode="MapDiagram" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Copy all other elements in between -->
    <xsl:template match="*[name() != 'Node']">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The script works fine. It processes A.xml and looks up each Node element in map.xml. Since @Src and non-@Src Nodes can be mixed, it is called recursively.

However, this script generates:

```
<Node Name="ParentNode">
    <Node Name="Child4">
        <Node Name="Child4">
            <Node Name="Child4_Sub1">
                <!-- Here are many other elements -->
            </Node>
            <Node Name="Child4_Sub2" />
        </Node>
    </Node> 
    <!-- Here are many other elements -->
    <Node Name="Child1" Src="Child1" />
    <!-- Here are many other elements -->

    <Node Name="Child2" Src="Child2" />
    <Node Name="Child3" Src="Child3" />
    <Node Name="Child4_Sub2" />
</Node>
```

So, the Child4_Sub2 is generated twice which is non-sense since Child4_Sub2 would need Child4 as parent anyway! But so far I found no way to prevent this element from being printed.

Do you have any hints?

Regards,
divB

Comment: This question is a model of giving the required information: sample input, expected output, current code, actual output, and description of how the actual output differs from the expected. Kudos!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change:

```
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="MapDiagram" select=
        "$MapDiagram//Node[@Name = $MyName]"/>
```

to:

```
    <xsl:if test="not(@Name = ancestor::Node/@Name)">
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="MapDiagram" select=
        "$MapDiagram//Node[@Name = $MyName]"/>
    </xsl:if>
```

**Here is a complete solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:param name="mapFile"
        select="'file:///c:/temp/delete/map.xml'"/>

        <xsl:variable name="MapDiagram" select="document($mapFile,/*)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="CurrentDocument" select="/" />

        <!-- handle Node elements in A.xml -->
        <xsl:template match="Node">
            <xsl:variable name="MyName" select="@Name"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$MapDiagram//Node[@Name = $MyName]">

                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$MapDiagram//Node[@Name = $MyName]/@Src">
                            <xsl:copy-of select="$MapDiagram//Node[@Name = $MyName]"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <Node Name="{@Name}" Type="{@Type}">
                                <xsl:apply-templates/>

                                <xsl:if test="not(@Name = ancestor::Node/@Name)">
                                  <xsl:apply-templates mode="MapDiagram" select=
                                     "$MapDiagram//Node[@Name = $MyName]"
                                  />
                                </xsl:if>
                            </Node>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>

                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:message terminate="no">WARNING: Node "<xsl:value-of select="@Name"/>" not found in map file, ignoring</xsl:message>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:template>

        <!-- handle Node elements from map file -->
        <xsl:template match="Node" mode="MapDiagram">
            <xsl:variable name="MyName" select="@Name"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="not($CurrentDocument//Node[@Name = $MyName])">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:apply-templates mode="MapDiagram" />
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:template>

        <!-- Copy all other elements in between -->
        <xsl:template match="*[name() != 'Node']">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied to the provided XML document**:

```
<Node Name="ParentNode">
    <Node Name="Child4">
        <Node Name="Child4">
            <Node Name="Child4_Sub1"/>
        </Node>
    </Node>

    <Node Name="Child1"/>

    <Node Name="ChildFoo"/>
</Node>
```

**and the provided "map.xml" is `at C:\temp\delete\map.xml`:**

```
<Node Name="ParentNode">
    <Node Name="Child1" Src="Child1/"/>
    <Node Name="Child2" Src="Child2/"/>
    <Node Name="Child3" Src="Child3/"/>
    <Node Name="Child4">
        <Node Name="Child4_Sub1" />
        <Node Name="Child4_Sub2" Src="Child4_Sub2/"/>
    </Node>
    <Node Name="Child5" />
</Node>
```

**The wanted result (not containing the unwanted repetition) is produced**:

```
<Node Name="ParentNode" Type="">
   <Node Name="Child4" Type="">
      <Node Name="Child4" Type="">
         <Node Name="Child4_Sub1" Type=""/>
      </Node>
      <Node Name="Child4_Sub2" Src="Child4_Sub2/"/>
   </Node>
   <Node Name="Child1" Src="Child1/"/>
   <Node Name="Child2" Src="Child2/"/>
   <Node Name="Child3" Src="Child3/"/>
   <Node Name="Child4_Sub2" Src="Child4_Sub2/"/>
   <Node Name="Child5"/>
</Node>
```

**General note**:  The code that is provided is quite complicated and messy -- there might be other logical issues with it. No XSLT 2.0 language features are used -- this is essentially an XSLT 1.0 solution. It would be a good idea to rewrite your code in a better form.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to directly examine the result document to see if a given node has already been emitted. You can get around that by outputting nodes to a temporary variable, which you can examine, and then output the contents of that variable later.

However, it's not possible to modify the internal structure of the variable's nodes after generating them, so ordinary iteration in that vein would be awkward. You could only approximate that by copying the contents with modification. That would be seem like overkill, but would be an option if the documents are not very big.

Normally though, we would solve this problem not by examining the output, but by checking against the already-processed input, or against a variable holding accumulated results. (Note that to accumulate results in a variable, you have to pass the variable recursively.)

Answer (score 0):

In addition you can use VBScript / JScript inside of XSL in order to make things that you cant make with XSL itself. You can create VBS function that checks if Row exists and return True or False. XSL will examine the function result and if it false, will skip the element generation and will move further. Of course you need to manage added rows in Script.

[VBScript example](http://blog.inspired.no/vbscript-in-xslt-127/), [JS Example](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-tipxsltjs/)